# How do you go from specification to implementation in a systematic way?

Tags: programming-practices

This sounds like a newbie's question, but please bear with me. I have 10+ years of commercial software development experience, and I still don't know how to do this properly.

I'm working on a pet project that's taking me months to think through all the subtleties. The actual code will be a small amount, maybe 10K LOC, but there are several parts to the project with some complex interactions. I sat down and finally wrote how it should work, in a way that is general but ready for implementation. Two pages of text, give or take. But it's not algorithm, it's a declarative description.

How do I go from a declarative description to implementation in a way that ensures I don't forget anything from my informal "specification"?

More specifically, my question is about the transition from a specification (written in somewhat loose terms) to a list of to-do items that, when done, implement this specification faithfully. This process of going from a declarative description of how the system should behave to a list of concrete, "procedural" instructions (do this, do that, write a test for this situation) seems to be quite non-trivial. How do I make sure I haven't missed anything?

Comment: This is quite subjective and no one has found a way to make it "systematically" efficient. It's like asking how best-seller writers plan their books. Some are archaeologists (they have a seed of an idea and they dig and clean and see where it goes), and others are strategists (they draw diagrams with characters, timelines, events, and links and develop history around those links). And for them, these are systematic strategies. What makes something systematic is repetition. Repetition leads to "refinement" and "perfection".

Comment: Note also that you are speaking about a pet project. Pet projects have no external force pushing you to have a result... No deadlines, no stakeholders, no customers, no stress, and no need to reach a goal. Unless you put yourself one or more of these stressing facts, you can get stuck in the design. Forever.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you're describing waterfall-based software development - come up with a detailed specification of what the software should do, review, add more details, review, etc. Do this until everything has been specified, and then you're ready to start coding! Once all the coding is done, move onto testing...except that by that point, the requirements have changed, the technology has changed, your interests have changed, and half the specifications don't make sense anymore.

While there are teams and projects and companies that still work that way (*cough* government *cough*), many (most?) prefer a more agile approach. Start with coding a small application that just does *something*. It could be that your app opens a UI window and prints "Hello, world!". From there, start adding features one by one, and fixing bugs, and thinking about details on the next feature, until all the features you wanted to add are there. At that point, you're done.

There are (at least) three huge benefits to working in this way:

1. You get a working version of your application much, much sooner. You can use it, test it, play with it, try and break it, and see what works and what doesn't. Maybe your idea of coupling the Foo into the Bar turns out to not work all that great - no problem, you discovered this early in the development cycle, and not after months (or years!) of detailed specifications and painstaking development and testing!
2. Related to the point above, you always have a version of the application you can use. It may not do everything you want, and it may not do it well, but it can do something - and that's better than nothing. You can use it to simplify parts of your workflow while you work on adding the additional features that will allow you to simplify the rest of your workflow. As a bonus, the more you use the application, the more you'll discover what works well and what doesn't.
3. You don't need to worry about the nitty-gritty details of all the pieces of your application that are far in the future. It helps to have a general idea of where you're doing, but you don't care about the details yet. Detail the next features you'll implement as they come to be the next features on your todo list.

Whether you work in a TDD way, or write your tests afterwards, or some other way is not important at this point - the important thing is to get an application going that works, even if it doesn't do much.

In terms of which module or part of the system to work on first, that depends on you and your application. Maybe you want to do the simplest one first. Maybe you want to do the hardest part first. Maybe you want the features that will give you the most benefit. Maybe you need to get something similar to market first in order to beat a competitor. Whichever you choose, though, remember that the goal is to get a working version of your application quickly, even if it doesn't do everything you want. So maybe that hard part could really be broken up into three smaller, easier parts.

Comment: Thanks. The way you proposed is the way I have always worked (and never had a problem), but this time there are subtle details that I struggle to keep in my head all the time, and the program will have subtle but serious bugs if I miss something. The process you proposed gets the job done, but it can be a bit chaotic (usually is).

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: your comment shows there are some things to emphasize in this good answer. You wrote *"subtle details that you struggle  to keep in my head all the time"* - that's why making a systematic TODO list is crucial - agile teams will often call this a backlog, some use specific tools for it. And you may distinguish between a detailed TODO-list for the next release, and a less detailed one of features which you intend to implement later....

Comment: ... and the second thing to highlight  is that by this approach you will have change and refactor existing code in your application on a regular basis. This has always a certain risk of breaking things which formerly worked, which is why regular tests are important, and why some invest into writing automatic tests will sooner or later become beneficial.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I go from a declarative description to implementation in a way that ensures I don't forget anything from my informal "specification"?

The formal way is to review your specification and identify how each requirement can be confirmed. If the requirement is testable, map it to an automated test. If it must be reviewed, map it to a review against the current version.

The informal way is to keep a todo list. The trick with making a todo list effective regardless of whatever formal processes get thrust at you is to always be willing to add to it. Sneak it into comments on tickets, comments in code, comments in stand ups. Never keep quiet about something that needs doing no mater when you think of it. Keep putting it somewhere hard to ignore until it's resolved.

If the resolution is to actually do it then enshrine it in a requirement and, if possible, a regression test to make sure it stays done.

Comment: Great point, thank you! So it boils down to "every bit that is important should have a test"?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe again not everything is testable. But you can still review. Inspect each version of the code and see that even your untestable requirements are satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Every requirement should be verifiable, and most should be testable. Verification is usually testing, but could also be analysis of the code or project documents, e.g. to demonstrate compliance with some standard.

During the requirements analysis, you should be thinking about how you are going to verify each requirement. That doesn't mean writing the test procedure at this stage, but you should be able to decide on the verification method.

Then, at the end of the project, you know you haven't missed a requirement, because every requirement has at least one test, and all the tests will have passed.